# Question about primitives

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

please if i have: $$F(t)=\int_{0}^{t} f(s) ds, \Phi(t)=\int_0^t \phi(s)s ds~\text{ and}~ B(t)=\int_0^t b(s)s ds$$ 
if we know  that: $$|f(t)|\leq \varepsilon \phi(t)t +c_{\varepsilon} b(t)t$$ can i deduce that $$|F(t)|\leq \varepsilon \Phi(t)+c_{\varepsilon} B(t)$$ by passing to the integral ?

i.e., $\int_0^t f(s) ds\leq \varepsilon\int_0^s \phi(s)s ds +c_{\varepsilon} b(s) s ds$ and this by definition is $F(t)\leq \varepsilon \Phi(t)+c_{\varepsilon} B(t)$

Comment: If someone have a comment or answer write it don't do "close" or -1 please

Comment: I think so, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 1):

From assumption we have
$-(\epsilon \phi(s)s+c_{\epsilon}b(s)s)\leqslant f(s)\leqslant\epsilon \phi(s)s+c_{\epsilon}b(s)s$.
Integrate both side from $0$ to $t$ will give you the desired inequality.